# Running Loop on field names in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, ajaxform

I am getting a correct result if I mention each field name in ajax, how can I get the same result using a loop.

**without loop:**

```
$("[name='efirst']").val(data.teacher.efirst);
$("[name='esecond']").val(data.teacher.esecond);
.
.
```

**Fields:**

```
<input type="text" name="efirst" id="efirst">
<input type="text" name="esecond" id="esecond">
```

I am also getting a correct result if I run loop on ID, but how can I achieve same on, NAME instead of ID.

**loop on id:**

```
teacher.forEach(item => { $("#"+item[0]).val(item[1]); });
```

Comment: What is `teacher` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it readable you can use es6 template literal

```
teacher.forEach(item => { $(`[name=${item[0]}]`).val(item[1]); });
```

read template literals here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals